Unable to get Cookie value when Jotform redirects user to another page
I have a condition that when a user shares his referral link then it sets a Cookie in the browser so that if GET value is removed from URL even then I can get referral.
I have checked in developers tool that Cookie is available across all web pages of my website. But the issue is when Jotform redirects the user to that page which contains PHP script to store the record in database along with referral value then it doesn't store referral value.
I have tried to add delay on the page but in vain.
I also checked the Cookie value by directly opening that page in browser which contains the PHP script.
Please tell me how can I fix this issue?
Here is the code inside header file. I have wrote this code before <html>:
<?php
if (isset($_GET['ref'])) {
  $cookie_name = "referral";
  $cookie_value = $_GET['ref'];

  setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/", ".candidateside.com", true);
}
?>

And this is the code which is being executed to insert record in database:
<?php
include_once "error_handler.php";
require_once "connection.php";

sleep(3);

if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    error_log("Connection failed: " . $mysqli->connect_error);

    // echo "<script>window.location.replace('https://buy.stripe.com/dR65lq5Rz8Xm704bIJ');</script>";
    header('Location: https://buy.stripe.com/dR65lq5Rz8Xm704bIJ');
    exit;
}

if (isset($_POST['submission_id'])) {
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($_POST, 1);
    echo '</pre>';

    $sid = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['submission_id']);
    $formID = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['formID']);
    $name = $mysqli->real_escape_string(implode(" ", $_POST['name']));
    $haveYou = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['haveyou']);
    $email = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $phoneNumber = $_POST['phonenumber']['full'];
    $veteranStatus = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['veteranstatus']);
    $ethnicity = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['ethnicity']);
    $dateOfBirth = $_POST['dateof']['year'] . "-" . $_POST['dateof']['month'] . "-" . $_POST['dateof']['day'];
    $howLong = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['howlong']);
    $areYou131 = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['areyou131']);
    $areYou132 = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['areyou132']);
    $willYou = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['willyou']);
    $areYou = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['areyou']);
    $haveYou136 = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['haveyou136']);
    $typeA = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['typea']);

    // Retrieve the referral from the cookie
    $referral = isset($_COOKIE['referral']) ? $_COOKIE['referral'] : null;

    if (is_null($referral)) {
        error_log("Referral cookie not set. Details: 
        IP: " . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . ", 
        URL: " . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . ", 
        User-Agent: " . $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . " at " . date('Y-m-d H:i:s'), 0);
    }

    $db_table = "combined_jotform";

    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM $db_table WHERE submission_id = '$sid'");

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        /* UPDATE query */
        $result = $mysqli->query("UPDATE $db_table SET name = '$name', haveYou = '$haveYou', email = '$email', phoneNumber = '$phoneNumber', veteranStatus = '$veteranStatus', ethnicity = '$ethnicity', dateOfBirth = '$dateOfBirth', howLong = '$howLong', areYou131 = '$areYou131', areYou132 = '$areYou132', willYou = '$willYou', areYou = '$areYou', haveYou136 = '$haveYou136', typeA = '$typeA', referral = '$referral' WHERE submission_id = '$sid'");
    } else {
        /* INSERT query */
        $result = $mysqli->query("INSERT IGNORE INTO $db_table (submission_id, formID, name, haveYou, email, phoneNumber, veteranStatus, ethnicity, dateOfBirth, howLong, areYou131, areYou132, willYou, areYou, haveYou136, typeA, referral) VALUES ('$sid', '$formID', '$name', '$haveYou', '$email', '$phoneNumber', '$veteranStatus', '$ethnicity', '$dateOfBirth', '$howLong', '$areYou131', '$areYou132', '$willYou', '$areYou', '$haveYou136',  '$typeA', '$referral')");
    }

    $mysqli->close();

    // Set the cookie expiration to the past to delete it
    setcookie("referral", "", time() - 3600, "/", ".candidateside.com", true);

    // echo "<script>window.location.replace('https://buy.stripe.com/dR65lq5Rz8Xm704bIJ');</script>";
    header('Location: https://buy.stripe.com/dR65lq5Rz8Xm704bIJ');
    exit;
} else {
    // echo "<script>window.location.replace('https://buy.stripe.com/dR65lq5Rz8Xm704bIJ');</script>";
    // header('Location: https://buy.stripe.com/dR65lq5Rz8Xm704bIJ');
    exit;
}


Where does this redirect happen? Is this still within the same origin, or are you crossing over to another site? (And why would you be redirecting to stripe, when you can't establish a database connection on your end?)

I have added a Jotform in main page. In the Jotform settings I have added a redirect link to the same website but page is different which is containing this second script of PHP. This is inserting rest of the values but not inserting referral value which is stored in a Cookie. And I'm sending user to stripe page even if connection is failed or any other error occurs only for user convenience as I also have this record in Jotform dashboard.

After searching a lot and debugging my code, I figured it out that I need to add html in my php script file so that browser can handle it as a web page. Because cookies will only load when a web page will load in the browser. So, I made following changes:

Header file:

<?php
if (isset($_GET['ref'])) {
  $cookie_name = "referral";
  $cookie_value = $_GET['ref'];

  setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/", ".candidateside.com", true, true);
}
?>


Script file:

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Processing</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta
        name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS v5.3.2 -->
    <link
        href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN"
        crossorigin="anonymous" />
</head>

<body>

    <h2 class="text-secondary p-3">Processing your request...</h2>

    <?php
    include_once "error_handler.php";
    require_once "connection.php";

    sleep(2);

    if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
        error_log("Connection failed: " . $mysqli->connect_error);

        // echo "<script>window.location.replace('https://buy.stripe.com/dR65lq5Rz8Xm704bIJ');</script>";
        header('Location: https://buy.stripe.com/dR65lq5Rz8Xm704bIJ');
        exit;
    }

    if (isset($_POST['submission_id'])) {
        // echo '<pre>';
        // print_r($_POST, 1);
        // echo '</pre>';

        $sid = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['submission_id']);
        $formID = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['formID']);
        $name = $mysqli->real_escape_string(implode(" ", $_POST['name']));
        $haveYou = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['haveyou']);
        $email = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
        $phoneNumber = $_POST['phonenumber']['full'];
        $veteranStatus = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['veteranstatus']);
        $ethnicity = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['ethnicity']);
        $dateOfBirth = $_POST['dateof']['year'] . "-" . $_POST['dateof']['month'] . "-" . $_POST['dateof']['day'];
        $howLong = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['howlong']);
        $areYou131 = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['areyou131']);
        $areYou132 = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['areyou132']);
        $willYou = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['willyou']);
        $areYou = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['areyou']);
        $haveYou136 = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['haveyou136']);
        $typeA = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['typea']);

        // Retrieve the referral from the cookie
        $referral = null;

        $attempts = 0;
        while (!isset($_COOKIE['referral']) && $attempts < 5) {
            sleep(1);
            $attempts++;
        }

        $referral = isset($_COOKIE['referral']) ? $_COOKIE['referral'] : null;

        if (is_null($referral)) {
            error_log("Referral cookie not set. Details: 
                    IP: " . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . ", 
                    URL: " . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . ", 
                    User-Agent: " . $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . " at " . date('Y-m-d H:i:s'), 0);
        }

        $db_table = "combined_jotform";

        $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM $db_table WHERE submission_id = '$sid'");

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            /* UPDATE query */
            $result = $mysqli->query("UPDATE $db_table SET name = '$name', haveYou = '$haveYou', email = '$email', phoneNumber = '$phoneNumber', veteranStatus = '$veteranStatus', ethnicity = '$ethnicity', dateOfBirth = '$dateOfBirth', howLong = '$howLong', areYou131 = '$areYou131', areYou132 = '$areYou132', willYou = '$willYou', areYou = '$areYou', haveYou136 = '$haveYou136', typeA = '$typeA', referral = '$referral' WHERE submission_id = '$sid'");
        } else {
            /* INSERT query */
            $result = $mysqli->query("INSERT IGNORE INTO $db_table (submission_id, formID, name, haveYou, email, phoneNumber, veteranStatus, ethnicity, dateOfBirth, howLong, areYou131, areYou132, willYou, areYou, haveYou136, typeA, referral) VALUES ('$sid', '$formID', '$name', '$haveYou', '$email', '$phoneNumber', '$veteranStatus', '$ethnicity', '$dateOfBirth', '$howLong', '$areYou131', '$areYou132', '$willYou', '$areYou', '$haveYou136',  '$typeA', '$referral')");
        }

        $mysqli->close();

        // Set the cookie expiration to the past to delete it
        setcookie("referral", "", time() - 3600, "/", ".candidateside.com", true, true);

        // echo "<script>window.location.replace('https://buy.stripe.com/dR65lq5Rz8Xm704bIJ');</script>";
        header('Location: https://buy.stripe.com/dR65lq5Rz8Xm704bIJ');
        exit;
    } else {
        // echo "<script>window.location.replace('https://buy.stripe.com/dR65lq5Rz8Xm704bIJ');</script>";
        header('Location: https://buy.stripe.com/dR65lq5Rz8Xm704bIJ');
        exit;
    }
    ?>

    <!-- Bootstrap JavaScript Libraries -->
    <script
        src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.8/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-I7E8VVD/ismYTF4hNIPjVp/Zjvgyol6VFvRkX/vR+Vc4jQkC+hVqc2pM8ODewa9r"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script
        src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-BBtl+eGJRgqQAUMxJ7pMwbEyER4l1g+O15P+16Ep7Q9Q+zqX6gSbd85u4mG4QzX+"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>

